# SpriteKit - Trying to implement a a 2.d.p timer which increments per 1 second. How can I do this?

Tags: sprite-kit, nstimer

I've tried using NSTimer but cannot get my head round it.
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with SKActions. For example...

```
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0f];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction performSelector:@selector(methodToFire:) onTarget:self], wait]];
SKAction *repeat   = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];
[self runAction:repeat]; 


- (void)methodToFire {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to do something game logic related, it's pretty easy to rig the update method to do what you want.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    // Handle time delta.
    // If we drop below 60fps, we still want things to happen at the same realtime rate.

    CFTimeInterval timeSinceLast = currentTime - lastUpdateTimeInterval;
    lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;

    [self updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:timeSinceLast];

}

- (void)updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:(CFTimeInterval)timeSinceLast
{

    lastEventInterval += timeSinceLast;
    //this is the part that will function like a timer selector and run once a second.
    if (lastEventInterval > 1)
    {
        lastEventInterval = 0;
       //do whatever you want to do once a second here
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why CFTimeInterval instead of NSTimeInterval?

Comment: That's what apple used for the parameter they pass into the update method, so it's what I used within it.  I have also used NSTimeIntervals for similar things with no issues. I'm not actually particularly clear on the differences between the two - they both appear to just be typedef'd doubles.